# using expect inside a bash script function

Tags: linux, unix, ssh, expect

I know this question is already asked trillion times in past. However my question is slightly different from the title.

I want to put the below chunk of code inside a function , I am not clear how I am supposed to do.

```
user>cat myScript.sh  

myFunction() {  
/usr/bin/expect  <<EOF    
#!/usr/bin/expect -f  
spawn ssh user@$1  
expect "assword:"  
send "mypassword\r"  
interact  
EOF   

}  

echo -e "Enter the server name"  
read servername  

myFunction servername
```

-----------Script ended---------------

I am aware of ssh keys and I can do the same using it, but I do not have authority to use ssh keys   as I am using a shared userID on the local server.

## Problem:

This script is not able to skip the password promt and login is getting failed like below:

```
[user~]$ bash -x login.sh  
+ /usr/bin/expect  
spawn ssh testUser@1.2.3.4  
testUser@1.2.3.4's password:  
[user~]$
```

Comment: While you're developing, use `expect -d` to run the expect script

Comment: Why are you writing an Expect script in such a pointlessly indirect manner? Just put the expect code into a file and run it directly. (Change `$1` to `[lindex $argv 0]`.)